# PyPi (401) basic auth failed

Tags: python, pypi

I'm trying to register a project with PyPi as per the instructions here

http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html

I haven't had much luck with the .pypirc file so now I'm trying as follows -

```
justin@justin-ThinkPad-X240:~/work/XXX$ python setup.py register -r pypi
running register
running check
We need to know who you are, so please choose either:
 1. use your existing login,
 2. register as a new user,
 3. have the server generate a new password for you (and email it to you), or
 4. quit
Your selection [default 1]: 
1
Username: YYY
Password: 
Registering XXX to https://pypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (401): basic auth failed
justin@justin-ThinkPad-X240:~/work/XXX$
```

All a bit strange as I can login fine to the PyPi site with the same credentials, and I am being very careful when entering them into the command line above

Can anyone shed any light ?

I realise there are a number of SO answers to similar questions but I have been through them all and they don't solve my specific issue

Comment: Who is owner of default project directory ? Are you try hack to pypi ?

Comment: I am not trying to hack PyPi! I am simply trying to push my first project to it!

Comment: So mean you create a project on pypi with your account ? And try connect your package directory with developer user/pass ? Where your global and local account settings ?